# Smooth edges in Maya

Tags: 3d, maya

I imported an illustrator text to Maya and applied a Bevel, so I have this:

[image: so I have this]

Now what I want is to smooth the edges of the letters, something like this I made 2 years ago:
[image]

I was able to do it 2 years ago but I completely forgot how to do it now
How can I do that ?

Comment: enable antialiasing?

Comment: Is this something I have to change in Maya or in the render settings ?

Comment: I don't know Maya and 3D questions are out of scope for this site (though we have a proposal [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-graphics)), but I know that in Cinema 4D, you would import your path and apply an Extrude Object to it.  You then click on the Caps tab of your Extrude Object's options and change the Cap to Fillet Caps with a convex edge.  You can then increase the number of steps, to smooth the edge.  I'm not sure if it's any help, but [here's a screenshot of an example](http://i.imgur.com/n70n5TO.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

in the channel box (right box on the screen) scroll down to poly bevel section that you made then in there change offset , roundness and segments to get to what you need

Answer (score 1):

select the edge that you want smooth
Then shift Right click and then select bevel option
Then play with the parameters you want.
HAVE FUN